# JavaFX MediaPlayer - Update a label for showing "currenttime" from thread/task

Tags: multithreading, javafx, task

I'm pretty new into java & generell programming.

I have a Group exercise where we have to program a mediaplayer that should be able to play music files (not video) and other features in JavaFX and right now I'm working on a "time slider" and the "total duration" and "current time"

Most of these things are working. My problem is actually the current time, because I have it running in a while loop. So the program doesnt freeze, i found out that I have to create a task/thread. The duration slider is working fine and changing the slider works pretty well. So the user can see how far his song is and he can even select the time he wants to jump to.

The Main problem is to get the current time updated.

If I hit "Play" the total duration gets calculated &
this code gets called:

```
mp.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            public void invalidated(Observable ov)
            {
                updatesValues();
            }
        });
```

right after that this method gets called.

```
String setCurrentTime = "0:00";
private void updatesValues(){

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (isPlaying) {


                //System.out.println(mp.getCurrentTime().toMinutes());      // Debug

                String setCurrentTime = "0:00";
private void updatesValues(){

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (isPlaying) {


                //System.out.println(mp.getCurrentTime().toMinutes());      // Debug

                String currentTime = "";
                int timeCurrentTime = (int) (100 * mp.getCurrentTime().toMinutes());

                int hourCurrentTime = timeCurrentTime / 3600;
                int minCurrentTime = timeCurrentTime / 100;
                int secCurrentTime = 60 * (timeCurrentTime % 100);

                if (hourCurrentTime == 0) {
                    if(secCurrentTime < (60 * (timeCurrentTime % 100))){
                        System.out.printf("%.2s:0%.1s \n", minCurrentTime, secCurrentTime);
                        setCurrentTime = currentTime.format("%.2s:0%.1s",minCurrentTime,secCurrentTime);
                    }else{
                        System.out.printf("%.2s:%.2s \n", minCurrentTime, secCurrentTime);
                        setCurrentTime = currentTime.format("%.2s:%.2s",minCurrentTime,secCurrentTime);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(secCurrentTime < (60 * (timeCurrentTime % 100))){
                        System.out.printf("%.2:%.2s:0%.1s \n", hourCurrentTime,minCurrentTime, secCurrentTime);
                        setCurrentTime = currentTime.format("%.2s%.2s:0%.1s",hourCurrentTime,minCurrentTime,secCurrentTime);
                    }else{
                        System.out.printf("%.2s:%.2s:%.2s \n", hourCurrentTime, minCurrentTime, secCurrentTime);
                        setCurrentTime = currentTime.format("%.2:%.2s:%.2s",hourCurrentTime,minCurrentTime,secCurrentTime);
                    }

                }


                durationSlider.setValue(mp.getCurrentTime().toMillis()/ mp.getTotalDuration().toMillis() * 100);

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    displayCurrentTime.setText(setCurrentTime);
    new Thread(r).start();


}
```

The Systemout is working fine. I just have some problems with the formating. Maybe also with the calculation/computing part.
The sleep part is not working, so the console gets spamed (prob. because of the milliseconds).
It looks like: 0:01 
0:01 
0:01 
0:01 
0:01 
0:01
0:02
0:02
etc..
The slider is working and gets updated but not the label "displayCurrentTime"

a workaround was to place "String setCurrentTime = "0:00";" before the method and "displayCurrentTime.setText(setCurrentTime);" at the end but before the new "Thread(r).start();"

Atleast its working now, but its not looking great. The problem is just, that the time sometimes gets updated faster than other times. 
Example: 1..2..3.4..5.6..7.8.9.0.10.11..12.13..14.15 (dots are breaks between each value)(prob. because of milliseconds)

Does anyone know how I could fix that or maybe make it possible in another way to update the label ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

1. You update the value of `durationSlider` from a background thread. JavaFX is single-threaded and the GUI must only be accessed from the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

   - You could use `Platform.runLater` here (but there's a better option, see point #4).
2. The `setCurrentTime` field is not `volatile` but you're writing to it on a background thread and reading from it on the *JavaFX Application Thread*. This means updates by one thread aren't guaranteed to be seen by another.

   - This might be a problem for `isPlaying` as well but you don't show its declaration.
3. **Every time `updateValues()` is invoked you launch a new thread!!**

   - As the `MediaPlayer.currentTime` property will be invalidated often you will end up with a lot of threads.
4. You use a background thread in the first place.

   - Not using a background thread negates the previous three points.
5. You use `currentTime.format(...)`. The `String.format` method is static and it would be better to invoke it as such: `String.format(...)`.

   - This makes your code clearer. As it is, people might assume `format` is an instance method.

---

*Regarding point #4:*

There is no need to use a background thread to update either `durationSlider` or `displayCurrentTime`. The `currentTime` property of `MediaPlayer` will be updated automatically as the media is playing (and notify any listeners each time). These updates will happen on the *JavaFX Application Thread*. All you need to do is update the UI inside the listener; as the computations are not expensive it is okay to do them on the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

```
mp.currentTimeProperty().addListener((observable, oldTime, newTime) -> {
  durationSlider.setValue(newTime.toMillis() / mp.getTotalDuration().toMillis() * 100);
  String formattedTime = ...; // your computations
  displayCurrentTime.setText(formattedTime);
});
```

The above code uses a `javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener` rather than an `InvalidationListener`. It also uses lambdas; however, if you don't want to use lambdas (or don't know about them yet), that code is equivalent to:

```
mp.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<>() {

  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable,
                      Duration oldTime, Duration newTime) {
    durationSlider.setValue(newTime.toMillis() / mp.getTotalDuration().toMillis() * 100);
    String formattedTime = ...; // your computations
    displayCurrentTime.setText(formattedTime);
  }

});
```

Comment: Hey first of all thanks for your answer. Yea, I saw in the debug that the thread method isnt smart hehe. At some point it reaches a high thread-XXXX value. But didn't expected it would get updated auto. Thats why I picked the while loop. But while the while loop was running, the program freezes :/ . I'm not 100% sure if I should change the code in update values or in the "isplaying". But i guess that doesnt matter. Will give it a try!

Comment: Seems to work. Used your first code and pasted my computation (the part after "int timeCurrentTime = (int) (100 * mp.getCurrentTime().toMinutes());" until the last "else" statement. It works much smoother now and gives no errors anymore, after ending the program with music still running in the background. Thank you for that!
Sadly it didn't fix the problem with the time 1..2..3.4..5..6..7.8, but thats because the calculated result gets calculated with milliseconds and formated to not show these milliseconds. So then it's showing "3" it's in real maybe "3.7" and therefore jumps faster to 4.